# Laravel 5.5 Storage::url() doesn't return the desired url with S3

Tags: laravel, url, amazon-s3, filesystems, storage

I'm using S3 for storage in my laravel 5.5 project
Everything is good and the images is stored in my bucket under my desired folder

using :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$path = Storage::put($directory, $file, $permission);

$fullPath = config('filesystems.disks.s3.driver').
            '.'.
            config('filesystems.disks.s3.region').
            '.amazonaws.com/'.
            config('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket').
            '/'.
            $path;
```

the full path then will be like :

```
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/iva-files/brands/logos/qweisiEC7H2SOV9ozjuOOBRxw399cTm2imnbJEXj.jpeg
```

I searched for better way to get my full url so I found:

```
Storage::url($path);
```

But it's returning path like :

```
https://ivasystem.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/brands/logos
```

What's wrong with my sinario ?

Comment: it will always return url of s3 because amazon s3 stores file with it's own url

Comment: @SalmanZafar this mean that the only way to return public url to user to view the image is concatenating it like what i did ?

Comment: yups. or either you can download it.but preferable to use to s3 url

Comment: I would recommend storing the path in the database & later you can use that path to show logos.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh I already store it in the db but I need to return the full path of the image in the response of that upload request

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename)
```

Comment: I don't need to specify disk because my default filesystem is s3.. what do you mean by $filename ? I don't have this variable !!

Comment: $filename was just an example variable instead you will use $path.

Comment: yes I edited this but still the url begin with https://ivasystem.signin.aws.amazon.com/console

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the [Official Laravel Documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem)

> The path to the file will be returned by the putFile method so you can store the path, including the generated file name, in your database.

So you should always store file path & file name in database columns so that later on you can concatenate path & name to get fill url to the file.

In my project I am already doing this.

Comment: the question is about return full path of uploaded image .. not about saving it into the db .. is there is any way to return full path without concatenation ?